# Sorting file by characters inside the datablock

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, text, awk

I have following data file

```
10

AA 21.1218 14.7862 0.0566269
BB 26.5036 14.5513 19.975
CC 7.82448 1.30605 50.126899
AA 10.0179 4.3786 21.232036
BB 4.80236 4.23255 36.217038
CC 31.475 9.60365 7.237505
AA 8.39392 5.89571 10.30242
......
10

AA 21.1218 14.7862 0.0566269
BB 26.5036 14.5513 19.975
CC 7.82448 1.30605 50.126899
AA 10.0179 4.3786 21.232036
BB 4.80236 4.23255 36.217038
CC 31.475 9.60365 7.237505
AA 8.39392 5.89571 10.30242
......
```

Each datablock is made up of 12 lines, and repeating 100 times (Total number of file is 1200) I learned from here that I can sort inside the datablock, but how can I deal with first two lines of each dataset? They are header lines, so need to be preserved.

So, I hope to have file like

```
10

AA 21.1218 14.7862 0.0566269
AA 10.0179 4.3786 21.232036
AA 8.39392 5.89571 10.30242
BB 26.5036 14.5513 19.975
BB 4.80236 4.23255 36.217038
CC 7.82448 1.30605 50.126899
CC 31.475 9.60365 7.237505
......
10

AA 21.1218 14.7862 0.0566269
AA 10.0179 4.3786 21.232036
AA 8.39392 5.89571 10.30242
BB 26.5036 14.5513 19.975
BB 4.80236 4.23255 36.217038
CC 7.82448 1.30605 50.126899
CC 31.475 9.60365 7.237505
......
```

I was trying

```
awk '{print int((NR-1)/12), $0}' file.txt | sort -nk1 > result
```

But this didn't worked for me. In addition, how can I deal with the first two header lines while sorting by first columns?

Thanks

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify exactly what your sorting criteria is but it looks like you want this (I removed the useless, obfuscating, and complicating `....` lines from the input):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NF==1 { idx=1; cnt++ }
NF==0 { idx=2 }
NF>1  { idx=3 }
{ print cnt, idx, $1, NR, $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | sort -k1n -k2n -k3 -k4n | cut -f5-
10

AA 21.1218 14.7862 0.0566269
AA 10.0179 4.3786 21.232036
AA 8.39392 5.89571 10.30242
BB 26.5036 14.5513 19.975
BB 4.80236 4.23255 36.217038
CC 7.82448 1.30605 50.126899
CC 31.475 9.60365 7.237505
10

AA 21.1218 14.7862 0.0566269
AA 10.0179 4.3786 21.232036
AA 8.39392 5.89571 10.30242
BB 26.5036 14.5513 19.975
BB 4.80236 4.23255 36.217038
CC 7.82448 1.30605 50.126899
CC 31.475 9.60365 7.237505
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm waiting for the book which you recommended to me :) BTW, Can I have some questions?. I'm seeing that you used idx and cnt++ to numbering the lines, but how did you deal with two header lines? Is OFS="\t" is for the header? Also, what is cut -f5- doing at the last?

Comment: `OFS="\t"` just sets the output field separator to the same character that `cut` uses as it's input field separator (aka delimiter) so the awk script adds 4 fields to be used for sorting at the start of each line and then the cut removes them again afterwards. I'd recommend you just look at the intermediate output from the awk and then the sort commands to get a better understanding of what they and the `cut` are doing. Also, add some print statements to each of the awk action blocks to see what they are doing and at which input lines each is executed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want stable sorting based on first field.  This script will do.  You need to end the data file with an empty line, otherwise code needs an END block to print the last content block.

```
NF > 1  {                        # contents section
    a[$1, NR] = $0               # collect by key+line number (for stable sorting)
}

NF == 1 {                        # header line, just print and move
    print $0
}

NF == 0 {                        # end of contents marker
    n = asorti(a, b)             # sort the index values into array b
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        print a[b[i]]            # print based on sorted indices
    }
    print $0                     # print empty line
}
```